# Kendo chart template with label, show html tag inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

hi i am using Kendo chart, i am using template to display label, I am formatting label by html tag but formatting is not working.
please check image 
[image]

Same is working with other kendo element but not with chart

below is my code

```
 $("#chart").kendoChart({
                    ..
                    seriesDefaults: {
                        type: "line",
                        style: "smooth",
                        labels: {
                            visible: true,
                            position: "auto",
                            template: kendo.template('<b>sss</b>')

                           }
                    ..
)};
```

Comment: The position `auto` will be ignored, it applies only to series of types `rangeArea` and `verticalRangeArea`  - [documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/configuration/series.labels.position)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,
I have found only this solution:

```
labels: {
    template: "Year: #: value #",
    font: "bold normal 15px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif", // or any font
},
```

it looks that html is not supported at all

Edit:

Well, I was a bit playing with that and next example what I have found out. True, it is not 100% clear, but you can format text with this code snippet as you need.

Point is that you can assign function to color or font properties ..

```
labels: {
    visible: true,
    position: "auto",
    template: kendo.template('#=MyFunction(value) #'),
    color: Test,
    font: Test2
}

function Test(e)
{
        console.log(e.value);

        if(e.value %2 == 0)
        {
            return "red";
        }
        else
        {
            return "blue";
        }
}
```

[Example here](http://dojo.telerik.com/abarU)

Comment: thanks but i want to give condition as well, like red color for critical point and green color for normal point.. how can i do this!!

Comment: I was playing with that a bit and edited a answer ... in my opinion it is very limited in format of labels but I didn't find out anything better ... Hope it helps you..